# In Vue what is the best way to pass data from a child > parent > higher parent?

Tags: vue.js, parent-child, emit

In Vue what is the best way to pass data from a child > parent > higher parent?

It seems that emit is used, but should emit be used to pass data from a child to a parent to a higher parent? If not, what is the best way?

If so, would the same emit listener, for instance: @dataHandler="data", be used at each parent up to the top parent, and does the data explicitly have to be stored in each parent up to the top parent?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to share state between components without any relations or parents / childreen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend creating an event bus.

This can be done as follows:

In main.js add

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue
```

In your component

```
this.$bus.$emit('theEventName', data)
```

Real world example template

```
<button @click="$bus.$emit('theEventName', data)">Add</button>
```

Real world example in methods

```
methods: {
  addItem (data) {
    this.$bus.$emit('theEventName', data);
  }
}
```

In the parent (or anywhere in the app) add a listener

```
beforeCreate () {
  this.$bus.$on('theEventName', this.yourMethod);
}

methods: {
  yourMethod (data) {
    // do your thing
  }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the listener

```
beforeDestroy(){
  this.$bus.$off('theEventName', this.yourMethod);
}
```